# Dynamic CSS Update Happens Too Often

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So the code below is working as intended with just one exception. The code obtains data from an API, color codes the data with jQuery, then checks every 1 second for new data. The part of the code that updates CSS to make negative numbers red and positive numbers green is working, but it will "blink" every few seconds before going from black to green or red. I imagine that's because the data is being obtained every second so it blinks black and then decides to go red or green.

So far, I tried an if/else statement so that the data would only update if the API gives a new value, but that didn't seem to work. Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks.

```
  coins.forEach(function(entry) {
    var name1 = entry.symname;
    var f = fullCGList.find(x => x.name === name1).id;
    var cgrequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url1 = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=';
    var idc = f;
    var url2 = '&vs_currencies=USD&include_market_cap=true&include_24hr_vol=true&include_24hr_change=true';
    cgrequest.open("GET", url1 + idc + url2, true);
    cgrequest.send();
    cgrequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (cgrequest.readyState == 4 && cgrequest.status == 200) {
    var cgresponse = cgrequest.responseText;
    var cgobj = JSON.parse(cgresponse);
    var cgprice = (cgobj[f]['usd']);
    var fprice = ("$" + cgprice.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits:2}));
    entry.price = fprice
    var cgchange = (cgobj[f]['usd_24h_change']);
    var fcgchange = (cgchange.toFixed(2) + "%");
    entry.change = fcgchange;
    console.log(entry);
  
    $(document).ready( function() {
      $('span.change').each(function() {
          var currency = $(this).html();
          var val = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9\.-]+/g,""));
          if(val > 0) {
              $(this).addClass('positive');
          }
          if(val < 0) {
              $(this).addClass('negative');
          }
          })
      })
    
    
  };}})

  addToLocalStorage(coins);
}

$(document).ready(
  function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        updatePrices()
      }, 1000);
  });
```

Comment: 1 second is too short, Adding class and browsers re-render page cost time,

Comment: Just to make sure I fully understand, every second you make a call to gecko - I imagine it's setup to be called often as prices change so that isn't the problem? But it sends results back in black. You show what it's sent back (onload function) and then change bits to red or green depending on their value? Could you refrain from showing what it's sent back until you've changed the colors? This would get round the color change black/red or green problem, but repainting each get will likely still cause a flash.

Comment: @AHaworth I think that worked, thanks. I just made a separate function for determining color and moved the function before showing what is sent back... seems to have solved it.

Comment: Good news, thanks for letting me know.